# How to avoid gap in the bibliography when there is a number but no volume

Tags: bibtex, formatting, journal

I'm trying to customize my bts to match the requirements of my institute.
My problem is followingoutput when citing articles that have a number but no volume:

> Amable, Bruno (2010): Morals and politics in the ideology of neo-liberalism.
>   In: Socio Economic Review, , 9, S. 3-30.

I'm using the natbib package plus my own bst. created by custombib.

The code in the .bts looks thus:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      ", " swap$ *
    }
  if$ *
}
```

I'd like bibtex simply to omit the field for the missing volume and directly continue with the number like this:

> Amable, Bruno (2010): Morals and politics in the ideology of neo-liberalism.
>   In: Socio Economic Review, 9, S. 3-30.

At the same time, I need the style to continue to print the other entries that have a volume like this:

> Amable, Bruno (2010): Morals and politics in the ideology of neo-liberalism.
>   In: Socio Economic Review, 52, 9, S. 3{30.

Comment: what bibstyle do you use?

Comment: I called it ioa.bts . It is a author-year style created by makebst.tex. Shall I quote the whole code?

Comment: can place the file anywhere for download ?

Comment: http://www.speedshare.org/download.php?id=AEC336461

Answer (score 3):

use this one:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  volume empty$
    'skip$
    { ", " *  }
  if$
  number empty$
    'skip$
    {  number * }
  if$
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Now the references without volume are fine, but in the others it doubles the volume combining it with the number making it: ...53, 536, S.... instead of ...53, 6, S....

Comment: yes, my fault. See edited answer